# What is this flying bug in Denver, CO?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It seems to be a flying insect about 2-3mm in length. It also doesn't seem like it's very good at flying. They seem to crawl around my desk until I try to hit them, which is when they'll start flying.

Location: Denver, Colorado, USA

They seem to come out more at night.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get a better image? Also, a description of the environment?

Comment: @arboviral that's about the best pic I can take with my iPhone, sorry :( the environment is my computer desk, it's pretty bright as I have a few monitors that are on all  the time

Comment: Could you get one with the wings in focus? Without some idea of wing patterns and venation there will be serious limitations on what we can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: @arboviral I added another picture with the wings spread. Hopefully that helps? :)

Comment: A little - but unfortunately probably not enough, I'm afraid! Based on the activity period, size and photos I had been wondering if it was a biting midge (Diptera: Ceratopogonidae) of some sort - take a look at some sample photos here: http://www.padil.gov.au/maf-border/pest/main/140521/49023 - but I'm now much less confident about that; the head looks too big and I can't see the distinctive antennae.

Comment: @arboviral they don't bite though. I think they are some sort of fly? I put apple cider vinegar into a cup and they all flew into it. does that give you a clue? I don't think they are fruit flies, they don't have red eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are **Scuttle Flies** (Order **Diptera**, Family **Phoridae**) (the wing venation, best seen on the lower left individual of the top photograph, is characteristic); the group has several hundred species in America north of Mexico.  So far as I am aware, the generic key in *Manual of Nearctic Diptera, Volume 2* (available online [here](https://esc-sec.ca/aafcmonographs/manual_of_nearctic_diptera_vol_2.pdf), pages 25 to 48) will still yield useful results, but cannot be used on these photographs.  The 30 pages in bugguide.net's gallery (starting [here](http://bugguide.net/node/view/14163/bgimage?from=0)) eliminate a few of these, but not nearly enough to go further on the evidence we have.